# templated iterator passing <N> to callback function

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I am trying to run a compile-time iterator like:

```
meta::reverse_iterator<2, 9>::iterate(callback());
meta::reverse_iterator<4, 7>::iterate(callback());
std::cout << "-----------------" << std::endl;
meta::iterator<2, 9>::iterate(callback());
meta::iterator<4, 7>::iterate(callback());

struct callback {
  template <int i>
  void operator()() {
    std::cout << "print !!" << i << std::endl;
  }
};
```

and this is how I've written the meta-iterator:

```
namespace meta {
    template <int Begin, int End, bool done = false>
    struct reverse_iterator {
        template <typename F>
        static void iterate(F f) {
            f.template operator()<End>();
            reverse_iterator<Begin, End-1, Begin == End-1>::iterate(f);
        }
    };

    template <int Begin, int End>
    struct reverse_iterator<Begin, End, true> {
        template <typename F>
        static void iterate(F) {}
    };

    template <int Begin, int End, bool done = false>
    struct iterator {
        template <typename F>
        static void iterate(F f) {
            iterator<Begin, End - 1, Begin == End - 1>::iterate(f);
            f.template operator()<End - 1>();
        }
    };

    template <int Begin, int End>
    struct iterator<Begin, End, true> {
        template <typename F>
        static void iterate(F) {}
    };

}
```

Right now I iterator calls `operator()<N>` But I want it to be able to call any arbitrary function supplied by user with template parameter `<N>` (not as run-time argument) How can that be achieved ?

also `boost::bind` doesn't work with it as it calls the function object of bind instead of the real function. So there should be some way to carry default parameters to the supplied functions.

Comment: Do you want a boost::mpl::for_each like thing? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/for-each.html

Comment: `boost::mpl::for_each` thing doesn't do the same. it passes that `N` as runtime argument. I want that as template parameter to function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do it directly, but if you really want it you can use a `traits` class that call member function for you, and for different member functions write different traits:

```
struct function_operator_call_trait {
    template< int N, class T >
    void call( T& t ) {t.template operator()<N>();}
};
template< class Arg1, class Arg2 >
struct foo_call_trait {
    foo_call_trait( Arg1&& arg1 ) : a1( std::move(arg1) ) {}
    foo_call_trait( Arg1&& arg1, Arg2&& arg2 )
        : a1( std::move(arg1) ), a2( std::move(arg2) ) {}
    template< class T, int N >
    void call( T& t ) {t.template foo<N>(a1, a2);}
    Arg1 a1;
    Arg2 a2;
};
template <int Begin, int End, class traits = function_operator_call_trait, bool done = false>
struct iterator{
    iterator() {}
    iterator( traits const& t ) : t_( t ) {}
    iterator( traits&& t ) : t_( std::move(t) ) {}
    template<typename F>
    static void iterate(F f){
        iterator<Begin, End-1, traits, Begin == End-1>::iterate(f);
        t_.call<End-1>( f );
    }
    traits t_;
};
typedef iterator<2, 9> fc_iterator;
typedef foo_call_trait<int, float> foo_traits;
typedef iterator<2, 9, foo_traits> foo_iterator( foo_traits(1, 2) );
```

Comment: and what about sending default paramaters to function ?

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, what default parameter?

Comment: assuming `foo<N>()` takes 2 arguments `foo<N>(int, float)` now I want to pass the values of that int and float to iterator So that It can pass them to `foo<N>(1, 2)` while calling. something like `boost::bind`

Comment: @Neel Basu: Do you use C++11? If so, you could add a template parameter pack to `iterate`. Otherwise, you'll have to overload `iterate` (with 1, 2, ... _n_ additional params).

Comment: `iterator` needs to be instantiated. `iterate(F f)` cannot be static as well